# react-redux simple calculator

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

New to react-redux (using with typescipt). I am trying to make a simple calculator with two textfields for firstNum and secondNum and have it display the output. Only three buttons, add multiply and subtract. Please help, im not sure how to deal with the textboxes nor how to display the output correctly.

Container:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { mult, add, sub } from 'modules/counter/';
import { ICounter } from 'models/counter';
import { ICounterAction } from 'models/counter';
const { connect } = require('react-redux');
const style = require('./style.css');

interface IProps {
  firstNum: ICounter;
  secondNum: ICounter;
  out: ICounter;
  mult: Redux.ActionCreator<ICounterAction>;
  add: Redux.ActionCreator<ICounterAction>;
  sub: Redux.ActionCreator<ICounterAction>;
}

@connect(
  (state) => ({ firstNum: state.firstNum, secondNum: state.secondNum, out: state.out }),
  (dispatch) => ({
    mult: () => dispatch(mult()),
    add: () => dispatch(add()),
    sub: () => dispatch(sub()),
  }),
)

class Counter extends React.Component<IProps, void> {
  public render() {
    const { mult, add, sub, out, secondNum, firstNum} = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={style.Counter}>
        <h4>MarkSlav</h4>
        <button
          name="multBtn"
          onClick={mult}>
          MULT
        </button>
        <button
          name="addBtn"
          onClick={add}>
          ADD
        </button>
        <button
          name="subBtn"
          onClick={sub}>
          SUB
        </button>
        <p>{out}</p>
        <p>{secondNum}</p>
        <p>{firstNum}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export { Counter }
```

reducer:

```
import { ICounter, ICounterAction } from 'models/counter';

/** Action Types */
export const MULT: string = 'counter/MULT';
export const ADD: string = 'counter/ADD';
export const SUB: string = 'counter/SUB';

/** Counter: Initial State */
const initialState: ICounter = {
  firstNum: 0,
  secondNum: 0,
  out: 0,
};

/** Reducer: CounterReducer */
export function counterReducer(state = initialState, action?: ICounterAction) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case MULT:
      return {
        out: state.firstNum * state.secondNum,
      };
    case ADD:
      return {
        out: state.firstNum + state.secondNum,
      };
    case SUB:
      return {
        out: state.firstNum - state.secondNum,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

  export function mult(): ICounterAction {
  return {
    type: MULT,
  };
}
  export function add(): ICounterAction {
  return {
    type: ADD,
  };
}

  export function sub(): ICounterAction {
  return {
    type: SUB,
  };
}
```

model:

```
export interface ICounter {
  out: number;
  firstNum: number;
  secondNum: number;
}

export interface ICounterAction {
  type: string;
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify a little more where the problems you are having are? thanks!

Comment: Sure! So my main issues at the moment are that neither the out, firstNum, or secondNum variables are being displayed on the page, but they should be initialized to 0. Also, I'm not sure how to make it so the user can enter in their own values in some sort of textfield for firstNum and secondNum (numbers to be added, subtracted or multiplied to get "out")

Comment: Ok so you have a few problems here, so it might make sense to break this down into a few problems. 1 - Your initial state is not firing it seems - i don't personally use typescript so sure but if you connected redux in correctly you should see those 0 values printing out. 2 - you need to decide where you want the user enter values to live, redux state or local component state would both work. 3 - you can use html inputs with onChange to update the users input for the numbers, how you do that will depend on 2.

Comment: see [trim-redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trim-redux) package.trim-redux is a tool for work simplify with the Redux in Reactjs. trim-redux removed reducer, combineReducer and action in redux usage process and let you work with redux like react component state!